# Maximum value of summation of integrals

Tags: calculus

Calculate the maximum value of

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{k} 3x^2 dx\right)$

I tried computing the integral which I found as $k^3$, but I am stuck from here. I was thinking that the sum could be the taylor series of a function, but I am not coming up with anyting. It seems like the only thing we have control over is how many terms, so the maximum value will depend on n?

Comment: It is a number depends on $n$. What do you mean by "maximum"?

Comment: Are you asking something about $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} k^3$?

Comment: no I am asking something about $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} k^3$

Comment: Then again: what do you mean by the "maximum value"?

Comment: What is the maximum value that the summation attains? This problem is from a math competition. I didn't make it up.

Comment: Then you might want to check what is missing. The expression you gave in your question is a real number depends on $n$. It does not make sense to ask what is the maximum value of it unless you considering $n$ belongs some subsets of positive integers.

Comment: I think n can be any positive integer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61399/discussion-between-chrismc-and-jack).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
An alternating series $\sum_{k=1}^N (-1)^{k-1} a_k$ where $a_k$ is a sequence of decreasing positive real numbers is bounded by $a_1$ and the sum decreases as you add more terms. Determine after which k the sequence $ \frac{k^3}{k!} $ starts decreasing.